# Success/error was not called - Parse Code 141

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to query the user class of Parse by passing in the users object Id, pass in a second object ID string, and save the second ID string to the user.

The function below works in a slightly modified way when not trying to access the user class so I'm not sure what's going on as the error I keep receiving is `Code 141 - Success/Error Was Not Called`

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("saveDeepLinkedMatchToUser", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.get(request.params.userID, {
    success: function(result) {
      result.set("currentMatches", request.params.matchObjectID);
      result.save(null, {
        success: function(user) {
          response.success(user);
        }
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("could not find");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will fail if the user being saved is not the requesting user.  You can force the permission by adding `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();`